# Saving and Loading XML File in IOS creates Problem In My Unity Project

Tags: c#, ios, xml, unity-game-engine

I am building a game with Unity3d and using 2019.3.3 editor.

I have a problem in IOS builds.

I am trying my game on android device and it is working fine however yesterday I tried on my game on an IOS devide and I had problems with saving and loading xml file on IOS.

I am using this code for saving:

```
SaveAvatar() {

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AvatarData));        
FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "avatar_data.xml", FileMode.Create);        
serializer.Serialize(stream, avatarData);        
stream.Close();
}
```

and I am using this code for loading:

```
LoadAvatar() {
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AvatarData));        
FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "avatar_data.xml", FileMode.Open);        
avatarData = (AvatarData)serializer.Deserialize(stream);        
stream.Close();
}

Also in OnEnable function I create my xml file if it does not exists: Without this code, it is not saving the game in editor or android as well.

OnEnable () { 
if (!File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "avatar_data.xml"))        {            avatarData.jobID = 10000;
            
SaveAvatar();        
}
```

These codes are not working in IOS even while serializing a class contains only one int.
( I tried saving another class to see whether my main save class has problems or not)

My save class contains variables types of:

Strings, Ints, Enums, floats, lists, other classes and self class variables

Here are sample variables from my class: (Samples from all types of variables)

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AvatarData{ 
   
public bool dead;

public string avatarName; 
      
public int age;   
    
public float health;

public AvatarData father; (Self Class variable) 

public EnumGender gender; (Enum)
        
public JobClass job; (Another Class variable)

public List<GroupClass> groups; (Another Class List variable) 
   
public List<AvatarData> children; (Self Class List variable) 
   
public List<PetClass> pets;    
public List<LogClass> logs;    
public List<JobClass> Jobs;    
public List<EventClass> tempEvents;    
public List<ItemsClass> myItems;
}
```

When I use SaveAvatar or LoadAvatar functions, In IOS, it bugs and code does not continue further lines. without saves it works fine.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code

Thanks

Comment: Never use simple string concatenation for system paths! Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which uses the correct path separators according to the OS. Note that especially `Application.persistentDataPath + "avatar_data.xml"` without a separator makes no sense as this would be a file **outside of** the `Application.persistentDataPath` folder!! Rather replace this by `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "avatar_data.xml")`. The reason why it worked on Android might be less strict file access rules..

Comment: When I have issue like this with deserialize xml I do one of two things 1) Comment out properties and classes in c# until I get the code to run to determine which properties are causing the issue. 2) Create a class with sample data and then serialize.  Then compare the serialize xml to the one you are reading to see the differences.

Comment: @jdweng I have opened and empty project and created a new class with one int variable.

Comment: @derHugo I have opened and empty project and created a new class with one int variable. Also I added path.combine but still not saving in iOS. Thank you for your replies

Comment: @derHugo 

   
       

        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + "player_data.xml")))
        {
            SavePlayerData();
        }

    

    public void SavePlayerData()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayerData));
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + "player_data.xml"), FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize(stream, playerData);
        stream.Close();
    
 

}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public int number;
}

Comment: Serialize the AvatarData Class and then compare serialize xml file with the avatar_data.xml.  I usually add data to the AvatarData Class so it looks like the file you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: @EvrenBuda nope remove that `+` in `Path.Combine`! It should be a `,` otherwise it is just string concatenation with extra steps. It should be `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "player_data.xml")`

Comment: @derHugo It is WORKING and I can't THANK YOU enough:)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments:

**Never** use simple string concatenation for system paths!

And note that especially

```
Application.persistentDataPath + "avatar_data.xml"
```

without any separator makes no sense as this would be a file outside of the

```
Application.persistentDataPath
```

folder since it results in something like

```
/rootfolder/applicationfolderavatar_data.xml
```

You need either a `\` or a `/` between them like e.g.

```
/rootfolder/applicationfolder/avatar_data.xml
```

The reason why it worked on Android might be less strict file access rules so you where allowed to write a file outside of the application folder, in iOs afaik by default you are strictly sandboxed to the application folder.

---

So rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which uses the **correct path separators** according to the running OS.

```
Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "avatar_data.xml")
```